# Nginx run php in the begining

Tags: php, nginx

I have a php file, path is at {WebApp Root Path}/api/InitStaticData.php

I want to run this php in the begining.

How to setup Nginx to run a php at server startup?

Comment: What does "in the beginning" actually mean?

Comment: I mean "service nginx start" or "service nginx restart",

Comment: So put it into the initialization script?

Comment: I got it from http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu